# Eliminacion de nodos intermedios

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, vscode

quería implementar un método el cual elimine un nodo entremedio, es decir, el método debe eliminar los nodos que se encuentran en las posiciones intermedias y el cual el valor sea igual al pasado como segundo parámetro

```
class LinkedList:
    """
    Lista simplemente encadenada    

    Atributos
    ---------
    __first: (Node) referencia al primer nodo de la lista
    __len  : (int) almacena el número de elementos de la lista        

    Clases
    ------
    LinkedList.Node: clase para representar los nodos de la lista encadenada
    """

    def __init__(self):      
        self.__first = None
        self.__len = 0        

    def __len__(self):
        return self.__len    

    class Node:
        def __init__(self, value, next_node = None):
            self.value = value
            self.next_node = next_node        

    # NO MODIFIQUE código que está por encima
```

Método mencionado anteriormente

```
 def eliminar_nodo(self, value):

        current_node = self.__first
        prev_node = current_node

        while current_node is not None:
            if current_node.value == value:
                if current_node == self.__first:
                    self.__first = self.__first.next_node
                    self.__len -= 1
                else:
                    prev_node.next_node = current_node.next_node
                    self.__len -= 1

            prev_node = current_node
            current_node = current_node.next_node
```

El problema viene cuando intento borrar un elemento intermedio repetido contiguo.

```
Lista original: [10, 14, 16, 16, 16, 19, 25]
nodo a eliminar: 16
resultado: [10, 14, 16, 19, 25]
output esperado: [10, 14, 19, 25]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se debe a que **cuando eliminas un nodo intermedio no puedes hace que `prev_node` sea el nodo eliminado en la siguiente iteración**, si `current_node` se ha eliminado `prev_node` debe seguir apuntando al nodo anterior al eliminado en la siguiente iteración.

### Lo que está pasando ahora:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El verde es `current_node` y el azul `prev_node`. El último esquema el resultado final.

### Lo que debería pasar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto el código debería ser:

```
def eliminar_nodo(self, value):
    current_node = self.__first
    prev_node = current_node

    while current_node is not None:
        if current_node.value == value:
            if current_node is self.__first:
                self.__first = self.__first.next_node
                self.__len -= 1
            else:
                prev_node.next_node = current_node.next_node
                self.__len -= 1
        else:  # Solo si no se eliminó el nodo prev_node debe cambiar
            prev_node = current_node 
        current_node = current_node.next_node
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias